# Getting error during running Cucumber feature file Unknown option: --plugin

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java

```
Usage: java cucumber.api.cli.Main [options] [ [FILE|DIR][:LINE[:LINE]*] ]+

Options:

-g, --glue PATH                    Where glue code (step definitions and hooks) is loaded from.
-f, --format FORMAT[:PATH_OR_URL]  How to format results. Goes to STDOUT unless PATH_OR_URL is specified.
                                   Built-in FORMAT types: junit, html, pretty, progress, json.
                                   FORMAT can also be a fully qualified class name.
-t, --tags TAG_EXPRESSION          Only run scenarios tagged with tags matching TAG_EXPRESSION.
-n, --name REGEXP                  Only run scenarios whose names match REGEXP.
-d, --[no-]-dry-run                Skip execution of glue code.
-m, --[no-]-monochrome             Don't colour terminal output.
-s, --[no-]-strict                 Treat undefined and pending steps as errors.
    --snippets                     Snippet name: underscore, camelcase
    --dotcucumber PATH_OR_URL      Where to write out runtime information. PATH_OR_URL can be a file system
                                   path or a URL.
-v, --version                      Print version.
-h, --help                         You're looking at it.
Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Unknown option: --plugin
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.parse(RuntimeOptions.java:119)

at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:50)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:44)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:20)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

I am getting this error during running my feature file.
PoM dependency is given below and I am using 3.2.4 Spring version with cucumber veriosn 1.1.5

Comment: Can you also add your code or explain bit more what are you doing and when are you getting this error!!

Comment: It's just simple test feature file it was showing error but when I moved to IntelliJi ,It's working fine. My be it's beacuse of Eclipse IDE ?

Comment: Try updating cucumber version to latest..

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are using a very old version of cucumber-jvm that is looking for

```
--format
```

instead of

```
--plugin
```

The latest cucumber-jvm usage text can be found [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/8d02a4fc155da5d5caffb7781c8ae72133b32562/core/src/main/resources/cucumber/api/cli/USAGE.txt).

Get the latest cucumber-jvm from the Maven repository as described [here](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm) or [here](http://toolsqa.com/cucumber/download-cucumber-jvm-eclipse/).

Answer (score 0):

Either its related with JAR library(ies) version mismatch or plugin(cucumber-eclipse-plugin) mismatch.
look Here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cukes/1urjr3ASq78

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar issue. The cucumber jars were old. So I updated it as below using maven repository

```
<properties>
        <cucumber.version>6.10.3</cucumber.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

NOTE: you can find the latest cucumber java in maven repository at this link [Cucumber jars maven dependency](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton/blob/main/pom.xml)